# Default file chooser for all types of files

Tags: android

Is there a code I can use to call file chooser for the external SD card so the user can choose any type of file and then get the file path of it? All the ones  I find on this forum was for Media gallery ? Or do I have to reinvent the wheel and write my own file chooser?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library project is best filepicker for android

https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser